# Open Excel file with parameter using PowerShell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, xlsm

I've got a requirement to fetch a last created .xlsm file from a particular folder. I managed to achieve it using the below powershell code:

```
$dir = "\\test\folder1\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir *.xlsm | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$filePath = $dir + $latest
```

Once I've got the file I need to launch the excel file and pass a parameter to it. In the past, the last created file wasn't required (it was using one master file) so I used to run a batch file that looked like this:

```
start excel "\\test\folder\file.xlsm" /e/TestEnv
```

Then using below code in VBA I was able to pick up the parameter when Workbook_Open() gets executed:

```
Function CmdToSTr(Cmd As Long) As String
    Dim Buffer() As Byte
    Dim StrLen As Long

    If Cmd Then
        StrLen = lstrlenW(Cmd) * 2

        If StrLen Then
            ReDim Buffer(0 To (StrLen - 1)) As Byte
            CopyMemory Buffer(0), ByVal Cmd, StrLen
            CmdToSTr = Buffer
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

I've tried calling many different powershell launch methods and none of them seem to include the parameter that's passed at the end of it including

```
Start-Process -FilePath $filePath -ArgumentList "/TestEnv"


$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($filePath)[TestEnv]
```

Any suggestions highly appreciated

Comment: The Excel `Application.Run` method supports calling methods in a workbook and passing arguments - you could use that in place of passing command line arguments.  https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm

Comment: @TimWilliams I need to call the spreadsheet from a powershell and pass a parameter. Application.Run vba code isn't applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dir = "\\path"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir *.xlsm | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$filePath = $dir + $latest
start excel "`"$filepath`"/TestEnv"
```

This resolves my issue